# Proper divisors of $P(x)$ congruent to 1 modulo $x$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic, prime-factorization

Let $P(x) $ be a polynomial of degree $n\ge 4$ with integer coefficients and constant term equal to $1$. I am interested in Polynomials $P(x) $ such that for a fixed positive integer $b$, there are finitely many positive integers $x$ such that $P(x) $ contains a proper divisor $d \equiv1\pmod x$ and $P(x+b) $ contains a proper divisor $d' \equiv1\pmod {x+b} $.

I know addition and multiplication generally do not see each other but out of curiosity, are there any such polynomials $P(x) $ with this property? Take $P(x) = x^4+x^3 +x^2 +x+1$ and $b=2$. After a long search through all $x < 10 ^5$, I find that only $x = 102$ satisfies this condition  ($ P(102) =(15\cdot 102 +1)(700 \cdot 102+1)$ and $ P(104) =(5\cdot 104+1)(2180 \cdot 104+1)$).

Comment: For $P(x) =x^4 +x^3 +x^2 +x+1$, it appears the gap between consecutive values of $x$ increases with $x$

Comment: Forgot to add in previous comment: the gap between consecutive values of $x$ such that $P(x) $ has a proper divisor of the given form appears to be increasing.

Comment: @Benjamin fixed

Comment: any ideas on possible lines of attack?

Comment: $P(x)$ factors as $(x^2 + \tfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}x + 1)(x^2 + \tfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}x + 1)$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\tfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}]$, which could be useful. I'll see if I can make any progress in this direction.

Comment: I found a paper that classifies all divisors  $d \equiv 1 \pmod x$ of $P(x) = x^4 +c_1x^3 +c_2x^2 +c_3x+1$. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://dro.dur.ac.uk/17370/1/17370.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiA1bC50N3zAhWn4YUKHcpAAIgQFnoECBMQAQ&usg=AOvVaw342CXbF6rnGuYbB1SK9MG6     This could be of much help

Comment: Take $P(x) = x^4 +1$. The paper uses two observations to construct all divisors of $P(x) $ congruent to $1$ modulo $x$: First if $ax+1 \mid P(x) $ then the cofactor of $ax+1$ is also congruent to $1$ modulo $x$. The second observation is that if $ax+1$ is a factor of $P(x) $ then $ax+1$ is also a factor of $P(a) $

Comment: You [conjectured on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/403542/385985) that for this $P(x)$, the values of $x$ with a proper divisor congruent to $1$ mod $x$ form a family of linear recurrence sequences. If this is true, I suspect this problem is very hard. For instance, if you replace the recurrence in your conjecture with the simple recurrence $A_n = mA_{n-1}$ with $A_1 = m^2$ for each $m$ and $n$, then this gives the sequence of perfect powers, and it's an open problem whether there are finitely many perfect powers with a difference equal to $2$.

Comment: (at least for this specific $P(x)$; perhaps there's a different choice of $P(x)$ that makes it easier...)

Comment: @Benjamin as you said this is most likely a very difficult problem. I doubt  there's any specific choice of $P(x) $ that makes the problem easier.